# How do I handle file access authorization in powershell across a domain?

Tags: powershell, directory-structure, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm working on a Powershell script that starts from the Domain Controller of a network, and it accesses the local documents folder of every user on every workstation. All I need to do is list the contents of the documents directory, as well as the contents of any subdirectories. The initial access works well, and I'm able to get a readout of all the items for a user's documents dir, but as soon as I start accessing subdirs, I run into an UnauthorizedAccessException error, and I don't see an obvious reason why.

```
Add-Content : Access to the path '\\***-021.****.local\c$\Users\*******\Documents\CyberLink' is denied.
At C:\***\Powershell\DocuTriever\Docutriever v1.ps1:30 char:17
+                 Add-Content -Path $path "$($item.Name)"
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\***-021.****....ments\CyberLink:String) [Add-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

(I've replaced some names for privacy's sake) I can see that the error points to the use of Add-Content, which implies it still was able to get the items with Get-childitem, but I don't understand why that command is failing. I'm accessing the name in a test-path check a few lines before.

Below I've posted the two main functions I use for this. Get-UserDocuments checks to see if a user even has documents, and sets up the output file. Show-FolderContents recursively goes into folders, and print out the contents into the out folder.

```
function Get-UserDocuments($path, $user, $computerName) {
    Write-Host "Working on user $($user.name)"

    $documents = "\\$($computer.DNSHostName)\c$\Users\$($user.Name)\Documents"
    if ((Test-Path -path $documents) -and (Test-Path -path "$documents\*")) {
        $path = "$path\$($user.Name).txt"
        New-Item -Path $path -ItemType file
        Show-FolderContents -path $path -folder $documents
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$($user.name) has no local documents"
    }
}

function Show-FolderContents($path, $folder) {
    $items = get-childitem -path $folder | Select-Object Name

    if ($items) {
        Add-Content -Path $path $folder
        foreach ($item in $items) {
            if (Test-Path -Path "$folder\$($item.name)" -PathType Container) {
                Show-FolderContents -Path "$folder\$($item.name)" -Output $path
            }
            else {
                Add-Content -Path $path "$($item.Name)"
            }
        }
        Add-Content -Path $path ""
    }
    else {
        Add-Content -Path $path "$folder is empty"
    }

}
```

Anybody know what I've done wrong, or how to track down the source of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Add-Content is what's throwing your error.
This CMDLet is used to echo data onto the end of a file. (Similar to bash echo "value" >> file)

You're effectively attempting to write either a null value or "$folder is empty" into whatever is currently your $path variable with your Add-Content commands.

GCI (Get-ChildItem) already has a folder recursive feature.
You can probably greatly simplify your code using that CMDlet.

Comment: I'll try for the recursion feature in get-childitem, though I still a little confused. I understand that Add-content was throwing the error, I'm just not clear on why. It doesn't look like I'd be using a null value at any point here.

Comment: Add-Content command was throwing the error. Add-Content is literally trying to write a string to the end of a file. This will fail if its a folder because you can't write to the folder in this manner. It will also fail to any file you don't have write permission to.

I'm uncertain exactly what each variable would be resolving to at the time, but as your intent isn't to add content to the end of a file, it's probably not the right commandlette for your need.

Comment: My intent is to add to the end of a file. Every time I'm call add-content, I'm intending to write a line in a text file that's being referenced by $path. A text file which is created in that first function I posted. Which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Ah, late night brain, it looked like your $path kept getting updated when I first glanced, so you'd have been writing to an ever changing file.

Having a bit longer look now.
Still feels like you're rewriting the wheel a bit, but our reasons are your own.